# Passing data from the server in python

Tags: python, sockets

I need to know how i can pass the data in this case to the valueList like once and then wait for a couple of seconds then pass the data to the valueList again. i dont want the data to be passed continously instead i want it to be passed down once then a few seconds then another few seconds.

```
screenw = 0
screenh = 0
while 1:
    client_socket.send("loc\n")
    data = client_socket.recv(8192)
    valueList = data.split()

    if (not(valueList[-1] == "eom" and valueList[0] == "start")):
        #print "continuing.."
            continue

        if(screenw != int(valueList[2])):
            screenw = int(valueList[2])
            screenh = int(valueList[3])
```

Comment: This whole design isn't going to work in the first place. You can't assume each `recv` will receive exactly one `send` message from the other side. You could get, say, 1-1/2 messages in the first `recv`, in which case `valueList[-1] != "eom"` so you toss it. Then the next `recv` starts half-way through a message, so `valueList[0] != "start"`. And so on. The problem is that this usually will work 99.99999% of the time when you're testing locally, and then you deploy to the internet and it fails 90% of the time…

Comment: But to answer your actual question: If you only want the server to send a message every few seconds, just have it send a message every few seconds. I don't know how your server is implemented (because you showed us the client code instead), but that should be pretty trivial. For example, if you spawn a thread for each client, just have the thread `time.sleep(2)` after each send; if it's built around an event loop just schedule a timer; etc.

Comment: Might be worth having a look at `Pyro` http://packages.python.org/Pyro4/intro.html#simple-example - It's a library that may well suit what you're trying to do, but at a more abstract and convenient level

Comment: Do you want the data to be spread out across a few seconds, so you only receive one message at a time?

Comment: @grieve spread across a few seconds